# Aurelia - Using animations to fade out a message div after 10 seconds

Tags: aurelia

I have got Aurelia CssAnimator working and thats fine however I assumed it would act on any div and anything within that div however all the times I tried to make a div with other tags inside have animations nothing worked. I had this and because it has  in side the div it fails to work.

```
<require from="./animateOnChange"></require>
<div animateonchange.bind="messageStrong">
    <strong>${messageStrong}</strong>
${messageStrong}
</div>
```

What I wanted to animate is a div that has a bootstrap alert class as per:

```
<template>
  <div animateonchange.bind="messageStrong">
      <div class="alert alert-${alertType}" role="alert">
          <strong>${messageStrong}</strong> ${message}
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I assumed wrongly that anything that sat within the div being animated would also be animated. Its not so.

How would I make these message alerts disappear after 10 seconds ie fade out using javascript? I have bootstrap 3..